# Local DTC is missing on server 2008r2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, msdtc

I've recently had an issue where MSDTC was unable to start up.

The error in the command line when running `net start msdtc` indicated that there were configuration issues.
I went into the registry and set the configuration settings to the same values as a default installation of MSDTC.

Afterwards, MSDTC was able to start up, however the local dtc seems to be missing in the component services.

[image: Master of Hide and Seek!]

I've since followed the steps [here](http://thedbavault.blogspot.be/p/msdtc-uninstall-reinstall.html).

1. `net stop msdtc`
2. `msdtc -uninstall`
3. `msdtc -install`
4. `net start msdtc`

And the steps [here](https://littlerasika.wordpress.com/2012/06/28/problem-with-starting-msdtc-and-missing-local-dtc-in-windows-7/).
Which is the similar procedure as above only with also deleting the registry configuration.

I've also put back a registry backup and rebooted.
And rebooted after reinstalling.

So far no matter what, the local dtc is hiding from me.
Does anyone know what might be wrong here, and how to reinstall the local dtc?

<strike>**UPDATE:**

As I was trying to find more ways of [installing the local dtc](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn464254(v=wps.630).aspx), I found out that the Powershell Commandlets are actually entirely missing.</strike>

If anyone has a solution/cause for this, that might help me along.

**UPDATE 2:**
By request on a different thread I redid the procedure, making sure the prompt was ran as administrator.
After running the commands the following events are found in event viewer:

> The Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator service was
>   successfully removed.
>   The Microsoft Distributed Transaction
>   Coordinator service was successfully installed.

**Update 3:**
I've found that the very first time the `Component Services` is opened after a fresh install, and the `Distributed Transaction Coordinators` folder is clicked the following error appears in the application log:

> The MS DTC Connection Manager is unable to register with RPC to use one of LRPC, TCP/IP, or UDP/IP.
>   Please ensure that RPC is configured properly. If "ServerTcpPort" registry key is configured(DWORD value under the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\MSDTC for local DTC instance or under cluster hive for clustered DTC instance), please verify if the configured port is valid and the port is not already in use by a different component.
>   Error Specifics:hr = 0x80070057, d:\w7rtm\com\complus\dtc\dtc\cm\src\iomgrsrv.cpp:2523, CmdLine: "C:\Windows\system32\mmc.exe" "C:\Windows\system32\comexp.msc" , Pid: 6096

Which seems to point to a firewall problem, but completely disabling the firewall and starting the procedure from step 1 did not help.

I'm starting to believe the only available option is nuking the server from orbit.

Comment: Does HKLM\Software\Microsoft\MSDTC\ServerTcpPort exist?

Comment: Does this registry key exist? HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Rpc\Internet

Comment: You may want to try renaming the Internet key temporarily to see if it allows the Distributed Transaction Coordinators folder to populate when you click it.  That may help localize the issue.

Comment: @GregAskew I renamed it from Internet to Internet_OLD. I restarted the MSDTC service and checked. The same results.